# Where to set the height of a component in the lifecycle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem where I am using a React grid component in order to display multiple charts. If you imagine the webpage is a `4 x 4` grid and I have two charts. Each chart being a `4 x 2` grid item. The grid library uses row height in order to say how large (y-axis) the charts are - so imagine if the row height is statically set to `100px`, then the gird is going to be a `width x 400px` grid.

The problem comes in because being made for different displays or accounting for if someone is going to have the application minimized (not full screen) the height of the component the charts will be rendered in is variable. I am able to get the height of the component's `<div />` by using:

```
return (
  <div
    className="content absolute top right left bottom"
    ref={divElement => this.divElement = divElement}
  >
  ...
```

and then calling `setState` in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const height = this.divElement.clientHeight
  this.setState({ height })
}
```

I can get the height of the `<div />` fine with this approach but the obvious caveat to this aside from eslint complaining is that it will cause a re-render of the component which is bad.

My question is how should I approach this if there is a better way to complete this same task? Is there another lifecycle method this would be better in (not really thinking there is). It's just that I have to wait until the `<div />` the charts reside in to be rendered before I can say how big the charts should be

Comment: Out of curiosity, can the height be set in a dynamic unit, like `%` or `vh`?

Comment: static unfortunately. the grid items within the chart can be resized to take up less grid squares so to speak, but the height of each square has to be statically set before hand